# Trying to understand XML Serialization in C#

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, xml-serialization, mechanicalturk

I am working on a Amazon Mechanical Turk survey project. I need help is understanding how the following class translates to XML when serialized.

```
public class ContentType
{
    public ContentType();

    [XmlChoiceIdentifier("ItemsElementName")]
    [XmlElement("Application", typeof(ApplicationContentType))]
    [XmlElement("Binary", typeof(BinaryContentType))]
    [XmlElement("FormattedContent", typeof(String))]
    [XmlElement("Text", typeof(String))]
    [XmlElement("Title", typeof(String))]

    public object[] Items { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ItemsElementName")]
    [XmlIgnore]
    public ItemsChoiceType[] ItemsElementName { get; set; }
}
```

I am making an attempt to generated the following XML document using my c# program.

```
<QuestionForm xmlns="[the QuestionForm schema URL]">
  <Overview>
    <Title>Game 01523, "X" to play</Title>
    <Text>
      You are helping to decide the next move in a game of Tic-Tac-Toe.  The board looks like this:
    </Text>
  </Overview>
  <Question>
    <QuestionContent>
      <Text>
        What are the coordinates of the best move for player "X" in this game?
      </Text>
    </QuestionContent>
  </Question>
</QuestionForm>
```

Both overview and question elements are objects of type "ContentType".

Below is my incomplete and incorrect c# code that Im trying to correct.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Amazon.WebServices.MechanicalTurk;
using Amazon.WebServices.MechanicalTurk.Domain;
using Amazon.WebServices.MechanicalTurk.Advanced;

namespace CreateHITProgram
{
    class FirstHIT
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create a HIT with the specified parameters.
            SimpleClient client = new SimpleClient();

            QuestionForm qnForm = new QuestionForm();
            ContentType qnOverview=new ContentType();
            qnForm.Overview = qnOverview;
            QuestionFormQuestion[] testQuestion1 = new QuestionFormQuestion[1];
            testQuestion1[0] = new QuestionFormQuestion();
            testQuestion1[0].IsRequired = true;
            testQuestion1[0].QuestionIdentifier = "1";
            ContentType questionContentType=new ContentType();
            Object[] questionItems=new object[1];
            questionItems[0]=new object();
            questionItems[0]="Swaroop";
            questionContentType.Items = questionItems;
            ItemsChoiceType[] ict = new ItemsChoiceType[1];
            ict[0] = new ItemsChoiceType();
            ict[0] = ItemsChoiceType.Text;
            questionContentType.ItemsElementName = ict;
            List<QualificationRequirement> qrList = new List<QualificationRequirement>();

            QualificationRequirement qr=new QualificationRequirement();
            qr.Comparator=Comparator.EqualTo;
            qr.IntegerValue=10;
            qr.QualificationTypeId="00000000000000000040";
            qr.RequiredToPreview=false;
            qrList.Add(qr);
            string[] rsgHIT=new string[1];
            rsgHIT[0]="Minimal";
            decimal reward=0.05m;

            HIT hit = client.CreateHIT("3LGOWEX152I2Q5FUSEN2GZFT8112F3", "My Hopes HIT", "Almost Last Attempt", string.Empty, qnForm, reward, 600, 600, 600, 10, "Swarup", qrList, rsgHIT);

            // Write the new HIT Id to the console.
            Console.WriteLine("Created HIT: {0}", hit.HITId);

            Console.WriteLine("Hit Location: {0}", client.GetPreviewURL(hit.HITTypeId));
        }
    }
}
```

Error Message when I ran the above code:

> Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: Cannot serialize
>   question form (contains no questions)
>          at Amazon.WebServices.MechanicalTurk.QuestionUtil.SerializeQuestionForm(QuestionForm
>   form)
>          at Amazon.WebServices.MechanicalTurk.SimpleClient.CreateHIT(String
>   hitTypeId, String title, String description, String keywords,
>   QuestionForm question, Nullable`1
>       reward, Nullable`1 assignmentDurationInSeconds, Nullable`1 autoApprovalDelayInSeconds, Int64 lifetimeInSeconds, Nullable`1
>   maxAssignments, String requesterAnnotation,
>        List`1 qualificationRequirements, String[] responseGroup)

Comment: You forgot to mention what's wrong with the code you already have.

Comment: Updated the question with the error message.

Comment: I don't see any code here that performs XML Serialization.

Comment: See your error message: `Cannot serialize question form (contains no questions)` I don't know what `qnForm` is but you don't add any question to it in your code....

Comment: @Robert Amazon MTurk expects the qnForm argument passed to CreateHIT method in XML datastructure format. I believe during the execution the object qnform is being serialized.

Comment: @Robert if you observe the error message it reads "(contains no questions) at Amazon.WebServices.MechanicalTurk.QuestionUtil.SerializeQuestionForm(QuestionForm form)". I think amazon mturk api is executing a serialization method SerializeQuestionForm.

Comment: @L.B. I do not have a specific question. But I want to understand how the class translates to XML data structure. How as in what will be root node and what will be the child nodes and how to fill each one of them in my c# program